# iText signature form field content not printed on paper

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext, digital-signature

I have a method that add a signature field to a PDF cell, using iText 5.5.9.

```
private static void addSignatureFieldToCell(String fieldname, PdfPCell pdfPCell, PdfWriter pdfWriter) {
    PdfFormField digitalSignatureField = PdfFormField.createSignature(pdfWriter);
    // If the PDF is not signed we don't show anything
    digitalSignatureField.setWidget(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
    digitalSignatureField.setFieldName(fieldname);
    // With this flag the field is shown on Acrobat
    digitalSignatureField.setFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    // This allows to show the signature on the signatures panel at the left
    digitalSignatureField.setPage();

    pdfWriter.addAnnotation(digitalSignatureField);
    // This is the event attached to the cell that tells the writer to fill the field with the signature data
    FieldPositioningEvents fieldPositioningEvents = new FieldPositioningEvents(pdfWriter, digitalSignatureField);
    pdfPCell.setCellEvent(fieldPositioningEvents);
}
```

This is working fine. After some steps, the information of the digital signature is on the PDF. I open Acrobat Reader and I can see the PDF digitally signed and so on.

The problem is when I'm going to print the PDF from Acrobat. The information of the signature is not shown on the preview, and of course when I print the file it is not shown either, so the box is simply blank.

Am I missing some configuration on the PdfFormField? what do I need to allow printing the signature?

[Link of sample PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14btI1E2QGXHtIGO9Kyjl-GfQnubEDgRg)

Comment: Please share a sample result PDF for analysis.

Comment: Just added the link at the end of the question

Answer (score 2):

The PRINT flag is an annotation flag, not a field flag.

You use `setFieldFlags`

```
digitalSignatureField.setFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
```

which sets some field flag you are probably not interested in at all. Instead you should use `setFlags`

```
digitalSignatureField.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
```

to actually set the flag that makes the annotation printable.

Furthermore you add the signature field to the annotations

```
pdfWriter.addAnnotation(digitalSignatureField);
```

but the `FieldPositioningEvents` does so, too, during layout. Thus, the signature field is duplicated in the annotation list which is something you don't want.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded iText RUPS tool trying to figure out more things, and I saw that the field were duplicated, but TBH I didn't know why. Also the documentation of iText, at least for 5.5.9 misses lot of information, so I was doing trial & error to figure out everything. Thanks